# Plotting through a long time series?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataset that gives out information about a product and i want to plot some stats about each month in a 2 year period. i have done what is needed to make it to this stage that i want it.

```
df <- structure(list(how_many = c(14L, 654L, 8L, 373L, 33L, 240L, 48L, 
242L, 2L, 45L, 239L, 5L, 29L, 206L, 20L, 29L, 194L, 49L, 25L, 
143L, 17L, 21L, 121L, 12L, 22L, 83L, 1L, 20L, 90L, 15L, 713L), 
    prod_vers = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "factor"), 
    when = structure(c(16801, 16801, 16832, 16832, 16495, 16861, 
    16526, 16892, 16892, 16556, 16922, 16922, 16587, 16953, 16953, 
    16617, 16617, 16983, 16648, 17014, 17014, 16679, 16679, 17045, 
    16709, 17075, 17075, 16740, 16740, 16770, 16770), class = "Date")), .Names = c("how_many", 
"prod_vers", "when"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")

    how_many  prod_vers   when
1        14          v1 2016-01
2       654          v2 2016-01
3         8          v1 2016-02
4       373          v2 2016-02
5        33          v1 2015-03
6       240          v2 2016-03
7        48          v1 2015-04
8       242          v2 2016-04
9         2          v3 2016-04
10       45          v1 2015-05
11      239          v2 2016-05
12        5          v3 2016-05
13       29          v1 2015-06
14      206          v2 2016-06
15       20          v3 2016-06
16       29          v1 2015-07
17      194          v2 2015-07
18       49          v3 2016-07
19       25          v1 2015-08
20      143          v2 2016-08
21       17          v3 2016-08
22       21          v1 2015-09
23      121          v2 2015-09
24       12          v3 2016-09
25       22          v1 2015-10
26       83          v2 2016-10
27        1          v3 2016-10
```

But i don't know how to plot it. i tried barplot but it doesn't work. Also i thought about plotting it like this: *considering the vast number of months with their corresponding product versions*:

One plot containing the 2015 year with its months and versions and one for the 2016 similarly. i am not sure if it would look tidy though

Also plotting each month with each version in their own plot would be a lot of plots.

To sum up how do i plot this?

Dataset: [mediafire.com/file/tt2l50nz4dzgaw6/DataforSover.csv](http://mediafire.com/file/tt2l50nz4dzgaw6/DataforSover.csv)

Comment: It would help if you could share the data (maybe via a link), and/or show us the code for your attempts so far.

Comment: how many prod_vers do you have?

Comment: `when` on x, `how_many` on y, facetting for the `prod_vers` maybe.

Comment: 3 versions. i will provide with an edit the whole dataset that i have created via r analysis so far.

Comment: Providing the dataset like this is OK but there is no way for us to read that into R ourselves. That's why I suggested sharing it via a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use facets to separate the data by group, like so:

```
data <- read.csv("DataforSover.csv")

colnames(data) <- c("X", "count", "app_version", "dt")

data$dt <- as.character(data$dt)

ggplot(data, aes(x = dt, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(app_version ~ .) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Count by Month & App Version")

ggplot(data, aes(x = dt, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(app_version ~ substring(dt, 1, 4)) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Count by Month, Year & App Version")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- structure(list(how_many = c(14L, 654L, 8L, 373L, 33L, 240L, 48L, 
242L, 2L, 45L, 239L, 5L, 29L, 206L, 20L, 29L, 194L, 49L, 25L, 
143L, 17L, 21L, 121L, 12L, 22L, 83L, 1L, 20L, 90L, 15L, 713L), 
    prod_vers = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "factor"), 
    when = structure(c(16801, 16801, 16832, 16832, 16495, 16861, 
    16526, 16892, 16892, 16556, 16922, 16922, 16587, 16953, 16953, 
    16617, 16617, 16983, 16648, 17014, 17014, 16679, 16679, 17045, 
    16709, 17075, 17075, 16740, 16740, 16770, 16770), class = "Date")), .Names = c("how_many", 
"prod_vers", "when"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")

df$when <- as.Date(paste0(as.character(df$when), "-01"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = when, y = how_many)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(~prod_vers)
```

[image]

How about this? You could use the `scales` option in `facet_grid` (e.g. `scales = 'free_y'`) to use different scales for the facets.

Comment: Here's the link [link](http://mediafire.com/file/tt2l50nz4dzgaw6/DataforSover.csv). i applied it and it doesn't work well to my data

Comment: Your answer doesn't show analytically per month. More like a summary of the months, can you please use the data i provided and make the months appear clearer?

Comment: You can change the range and amount of axis ticks as you wish. [Here's a tutorial](http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html).